# Specify table for rails .where

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Can't find same question. How can I specify select.where for model?

I need to select from different tables by one model and want to get something like this in controller:

```
params[:id] = 1248  // here is example of request params
id=params[:id]      // this id goes to message SQL like table name with prefix:
Message(id).all => select * from messages_1248
```

How can I get something like this?

Thanks for answers!

UPD:

I have one table with users and many tables with messages (each table is for one pair of users). In users table there is 'messages' column with messages tables id's. And inside user_controller I need to run a query like in my question. Maybe anybody can share an example?

Comment: to select more table, it depends with your data structure (for example active record relation connections) whether it's has_many, has_one / others, and some times we also using scope which inside scope we use sql join tables

Comment: I'v one table with users and many tables with messages (each table is for one pair of users). In users table there is 'messages' column with messages tables id's. And inside user_controller i need to do querry like in my question. Maybe you can share example?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

how about little bit change the design, with just 2 tables (user and message) just idea with details below
user table (id,name)
messages table(user_id,message_text)
you setup the relation user has_many messages (please see this link for more guide http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-association

user.rb

```
has_many  :memberships
```

message.rb

```
belongs_to :user
```

for example you need to access user with specific id and the messages for this user
inside users_controller.rb

```
  def show
    @user     = User.find(params[:id])
    # this find user
    @messages = @user.messages
    # get all the messages for specific users
  end
```

Comment: I was think about this. But I don't sure about this method stability with f.e. million of messages (1000 messages for 1000 users it's not so much). I scared by tables with too many rows :D

Comment: if you using ransack gem combined with pagination gem ( will_paginate / kaminari gem), then you don't have to worry about the stability loading the data, here is link for ransack https://github.com/activerecord-hackery/ransack

Comment: Thanx a lot, mate! I'll try to do this and then mark this like answer if it'll work for me :)

Comment: Looks like this way can solve my problem :) Thanx again! But I still need to test it with a big amount of messages.